# Dynamically creating multidimensional arrays to be encoded into JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a section of an array defined:

```
$arrData['categories'] = array();
array_push($arrData['categories'],array("category" => array(array("label"=>"Beef"),array("label"=>"Chicken"))));
array_push($arrDAta['categories'][0]['category'],array("label"=>"pork"));
```

The arrays are nested so that it encodes into JSON properly with all the {[{[{[]}]}]} formatted properly.

However, I need to create these types of meats dynamically, not statically. When I try to add onto the array in the third line of code to simulate dynamic creation, it throws an error:

> Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be an array, null given

Well, `$arrData['categories'][0]['category]` IS an array, so why does it shoot me down?

To show myself that I'm not crazy, I var_dump `$arrData['categories'][0]['category']` and get an array of size 1:

```
array (size=1)
'category' =>
 array (size=2)
   0 => 
     array (size=1)
       'label' => string 'Beef' (length=4)
   1 => 
     array (size=1)
       'label' => string 'Chicken' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the capitalization. In the third line the variable $arrDAta is capitalized differently than the others ($arrData)

Comment: Excuse me while I shut down my computer and go to bed. Apparently I am the reason why we cannot have nice things. ;)